# How to re-enable the TextMate2 's bundle

Tags: textmatebundles, textmate2

I am using Tm2.

For some reasons,I disabled a bundle with "Edit with Bundles",but when I reopen the Tm2 and re-select the bundles such as Avian,it becomes grey cause it is disabled.

So the question ,I can not select the bundle which I have disabled,any help?

Thanks

--Ford

Comment: I think I get the answer.

There is a directory: ~/Library/Application Support/Avian/Bundles ,and the disabled bundles are there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Under the directory

```
~/Library/Application Support/Avian/Bundles/
```

you should find the bundle which you disabled. Use "Open With" to open the bundle in Textmate2 (or any of your favorite editor ;) ) and inside the bundle root you should find the Info.plist file.
There set the isDisable key to false by changing this:

```
<key>isDisabled</key>
<true/>
```

to

```
<key>isDisabled</key>
<false/>
```

Reload textmate2 and you should find the bundle enabled again. I do wish there was a way to do this from within the Bundle editor. Hopefully when they release a stable version, they would have this option.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with the Source bundle, so I fixed it somewhat brutally:

```
mv Library/Application\ Support/Avian/Bundles/Source.tmbundle /tmp
```